# Difficult inequality with three real variables

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

For any real $e, t, \sigma$ such that
\begin{aligned}
\label{s}
     0&<e<1\,,\\
     0&<t<\pi\,,\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)\\
-\pi/2&\leqslant\sigma\leqslant\pi/2
\end{aligned}
the inequality
\begin{aligned}
(1-e^2\cos^2\sigma)\eta&+(1+e\cos(t-\sigma))(e\eta\cos\sigma\cos t
                                                         +e\sin t)>\\
                       &>(1+e\cos(t-\sigma))\sqrt{1-(e\eta\cos\sigma\sin t-
                                                    e\cos t)^2}\,,\qquad(2)
\end{aligned}
where $\eta=\sqrt{1-e^2}$, holds.

I have "proved" (2) numerically by three-dimensional brute-force method over the set (1). I used a three-dimensional grid with a high partition density in my C++ program. So I am sure that (2) holds on (1). Moreover, I proved (2) analitically for special case $\sigma=-\pi/2$.

In order to prove (2) analitically, I suppose that one have to do as follows. Denote for shortness
\begin{aligned}
\tau&=1-e^2\cos^2\sigma\,,\\
\gamma&=1+e\cos(t-\sigma)\,,\\
\delta_1&=\eta\cos\sigma\cos t+\sin t\,,\\
\delta_2&=\eta\cos\sigma\sin t-\cos t\,.
\end{aligned}
It is easy to prove that the expression under the root in (2) is positive on (1). Further, suppose that the left-hand side of (2) is also positive (at least nonnegative) on (1). Then (2) holds if and only if the square of the left-hand side of (2) is greater than the square of its right-hand side. After squaring both sides of (2) and noticing that
$$
\delta^2_1+\delta^2_2=1+\eta^2\cos^2\sigma
$$
one obtains after some computations the following inequality
\begin{equation}
\frac{\tau\eta}{\gamma^2}+\frac{2e\delta_1}{\gamma}>\eta\qquad\qquad(3)
\end{equation}
that has to be proved. So if the left-hand side of (2)
\begin{equation}
\tau\eta+e\gamma\delta_1\geqslant0\,\qquad\qquad\qquad(4)
\end{equation}
on (1), it only remains to establish the validity of (3) on (1).

In my opinion the task (1), (3), (4) is simpler than the original task (1), (2), but I am stuck at this stage. Maybe there are some other ways to deal with (1), (2), for example without the squaring (2)? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you chose a right way. I followed it and proved inequality (3). I failed to prove inequality (4), but we also need it to be true because the right hand side of inequality (2) is positive.

We can prove (3) as follows. Since  $\gamma>0$, we have to prove

$$\tau\eta>\gamma(\eta\gamma-2e\delta_1)$$

$$(1-e^2\cos^2\sigma)\eta>(1+e\cos t\cos\sigma+e\sin t\sin\sigma)(\eta(1+e\cos t\cos\sigma+e\sin t\sin\sigma)-2e(\eta\cos\sigma\cos t+\sin t))$$

After routine transformations we obtain

$$0>\eta e\sin^2t+2\eta\sin t\sin\sigma-2\sin t-2e\sin t\cos t\cos\sigma-2e\sin^2 t\sin\sigma$$

Since $\sin t>0$, this is equivalent to

$$0>\eta e\sin t+2\eta\sin\sigma-2-2e\cos t\cos\sigma-2e\sin t\sin\sigma$$

We show that

$$2>\eta e\sin t+2\eta\sin\sigma-2e\cos t\cos\sigma-2e\sin t\sin\sigma.$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$(\eta-e\sin t)\sin\sigma-e\cos t\cos\sigma\le\sqrt{(\eta-e\sin t)^2+(e\cos t)^2}=\sqrt{1-2\eta e\sin t}.$$

Put $x=\eta e\sin t$. Then $0<x\le \frac{\eta^2+e^2}2=\frac 12$ and we have to check that

$$2>x+2\sqrt{1-2x}$$

$$(2-x)^2>4(1-2x)$$

$$x+4>0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Continuity of the functions
\begin{align}
f(e, t, \sigma) &\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \mathrm{LHS}(2) =
                                            \tau\eta+e\gamma\delta_1,\\
g(e, t, \sigma) &\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \mathrm{RHS}(2) =
                                            \gamma\sqrt{1-e^2\delta_2^2},\\
h(e, t, \sigma) &\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} f(e, t, \sigma)-g(e, t, \sigma)
\end{align}
on the set (1) completes the proof. We want to show that $h(e, t, \sigma)>0$ on (1).

Suppose that there is a point $(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)\in(1)$ such that
$h(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)=0$. Then
$$
  f(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)=g(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)\Rightarrow
  \bigl[f(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)\bigr]^2=\bigl[g(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)\bigr]^2.
$$
Contradiction, because as we already know,
$$
\bigl[f(e, t, \sigma)\bigr]^2>\bigl[g(e, t, \sigma)\bigr]^2
$$
everywhere in (1). By continuity of $h(e, t, \sigma)$ it means that
$h(e, t, \sigma)$ is either positive or negative on (1). Since we saw that
there are subsets of (1) where $h$ is positive, we conclude that
$h(e, t, \sigma)>0$ everywhere in (1).

Comment: Very nice! The proof is correct, but I have a few remarks. The notation $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is not a general brackets, but an integer part of a number, for instance $\lfloor 2.3\rfloor =2$. Next, $h(e, t, \sigma)$ is either positive or negative on (1) provided $h(e, t, \sigma)$ attains no zero values at (1) and (1) is connected (which is true).

Comment: At last, since the function $g$ is non-negative, if the equality $f(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)=g(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)$ holds then $f(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)$ is non-negative, but we already proved that in this case $f(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)>g(e_0, t_0, \sigma_0)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Interesting. $>$ makes things different. 
We often encounter the problem of proving that $f(x) \ge g(x)$ where $g(x)\ge 0$,
and we need to prove that $f(x)\ge 0$ and $f^2(x) \ge g^2(x)$.
However, if the problem is to prove that $f(x) > g(x)$ where $g(x)\ge 0$,
we may prove that $f^2(x) > g^2(x)$ and use the method of continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your answer, Alex. I suppose that (4) is harder than (3) to be dealt with and therefore I hope that the most difficult part of the task thanks to your efforts is overcome. As for the rest task (1, 4) here is my simple thoughts about it.

First of all, if $0<t\leqslant\pi/2$, then $\cos t\geqslant0$ and (4) obviously holds on (1). Thus putting $\varphi=t-\pi/2$ the inequality (4) takes the form
$$
\tau\eta+(1+e\sin(\sigma-\varphi))(e\cos\varphi-e\eta\cos\sigma\sin\varphi)>0.\qquad (5)
$$
We have to verify that (5) is valid on the set
\begin{align}
0 &< e < 1,\\
0 &< \varphi < \pi/2,\qquad\qquad\qquad(6)\\
-\pi/2 &\leqslant\sigma\leqslant\pi/2.
\end{align}

Further, we can prove (5, 6) for every $0<e<1/2$ as follows. We obviously have
\begin{align}
(1+e\sin(\sigma-\varphi))\leqslant 1+e,\\
(e\cos\varphi-e\eta\cos\sigma\sin\varphi)\geqslant-e\eta.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
(1+e\sin(\sigma-\varphi))(e\cos\varphi-e\eta\cos\sigma\sin\varphi)\geqslant-e\eta(1+e)
$$
This is rough (not exact) low bound for $e\gamma\delta_1$ in (4). So
\begin{align}
\tau\eta-e\eta(1+e) &> 0\\
               \tau &> e(1+e)\\
                    1 &> e+e^2(1+cos^2\sigma)\\
                    1 &> e+2e^2\\
             2e^2+e-1 &< 0.
\end{align}
The most frustrating thing here is that the quadratic polynomial $2e^2+e-1$ is negative only for $0\leqslant e<1/2$.

So the task (1, 2) can be reduced to the proving the validity of (5) on the set
\begin{align}
1/2 &\leqslant e < 1,\\
0 &< \varphi < \pi/2,\qquad\qquad\qquad(7)\\
-\pi/2 &\leqslant\sigma\leqslant\pi/2.
\end{align}

I think that one has to introduce a new variable $s=1-e$ or somthing like that. Ironically, from the geometrical content of this problem it clearly follows that
the more e, the bigger difference between the right and the left hand side of (2)
should be. That difference must decrease when decrease $\sin t$. And when $\sin t=0$
the left hand side of (2) is equal to the its right hand-side.

I thought about more poweful tools, like expanding these quantities in Maclaurin series in e, or trigonometric series, and investigating their coefficients. Maybe one ought to try use complex representation on trigonometric expressions.

Comment: In (5) it suffices to have "$\le$" instead of "$<$". I simplified a bit its left hand side to  $$\eta-e\eta\sin\varphi\cos\sigma+e\cos\varphi+e^2\cos\varphi\sin(\sigma-\varphi)-
e^2\eta\cos\varphi\cos\sigma\cos(\sigma-\varphi),$$ but failed to go farther.

Comment: After my comment I tried different analytical approaches to prove the inequality. This is a headache. Different groupings were not sufficient, after a differentiation I found myself in a fog, Lagrange multipliers method after a few steps leads to an equation of forth degree. On the other hand, I found related spherical coordinates $(e\cos\varphi, e\sin\varphi,\eta)$.

Comment: I think I failed because the analytic problem is too complicated. I suggest that if I had an original geometry problem I would try to build its simple analytic model (or even proceed without such a model at all). Difference between analytical and geometrical approaches was considered by an ideologist of the first of them,  V. Tikhomirov in a paper “[Geometry or analysis](http://kvant.mccme.ru/1990/10/geometriya_ili_analiz.htm)”. I read it when I was a  schoolboy and looking at your name I hope you are able to read it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definetly read that Tikhomirov's article. Actually, I chose probably a very complicated way to prove my rather simple (hopefully simple) geometrical problem. This is probably because I am celestial mechanist rather than pure mathematician. This problem is related to the ellipse and some arc of a some circumference. This problem is pretty simple formulated and for many people I think is very obvious to be specially proved. But for me it is not obvious. If in your papers there is your valid e-mail, I can if you wish show this geometrical statement to be proved.

Comment: OK. The e-mails in my papers are valid.