# Find the border radius tangent's relative coordinates in a rhombus

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have this rhombus. The width `w` and height `h`, and the coordinates of `M` the intersection of the diagonals is also given. The border radius `r` is given.

[image]

Notice how the circle with center `O` and radius `r` is tangent to the segments `[AD]` in the point `T`.

In this diagram, $w = AC$ and $h = BD$, so they are interchangeable below.

**I want to find the coordinates of the point T, the intersection point between the border radius circle and the side of the rhombus, relative to M.**

**So I need a way to express the distance `TI` and the distance `IM` only in terms of `w`, `h`, and `r`.**

(finding `IM` is the same as finding `DI`, since $IM=\frac{w}{2}-DI$)

There are four right angle triangles of interest:

- `TDO`
- `ADM`
- `TDI`
- `TIO`

Here are the equations I have obtained inside each triangle:

## Triangle TDO

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{DT}{DO}$

$\sin(\theta)=\frac{r}{DO}$

$\tan(\theta)=\frac{r}{DT}$

$DO^{2}=DT^{2}+r^{2}$

## Triangle ADM

$\tan(\theta)=\frac{w}{h}$

## Triangle TDI

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{DI}{DT}$

$\sin(\theta)=\frac{TI}{DT}$

$\tan(\theta)=\frac{TI}{DI}$

$DT^{2}=DI^{2}+TI^{2}$

## Triangle TIO

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{TI}{r}$

$\sin(\theta)=\frac{IO}{r}$

$\tan(\theta)=\frac{IO}{TI}$

$r^{2}=TI^{2}+IO^{2}$

There's no system of equations solver online willing to solve this, and I am unsure how to proceed to solve for the unknowns `TI` and `IM` in terms of the knowns `w`, `h`, and `r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this as a *comment*. Someone willing to convert it to an answer can do it.
Let $M=(0,0),\,D=(0,\frac y2),\, C=(\frac x2,0)$ where I use $x,y$ instead of $w,h$.
$T$ being on the line $CD$ is $T=tC+(1-t)D$ and $O$ being on the line $MD$ is $O=sD$.
We have $$(O-T)\cdot (C-D)=0,\ (O-T)^2=r^2,$$ [solving](https://tio.run/##RchLCsMgFADAvafIUlONn6Xy7lDIMqQgGmigqRAfpUU8u0mh0N0wm8f7snlcg28tWChvabiqLp5U/CNNdQS1BezDhWqBrI@OpDPyF1lZGNPjtUyFBhHZQFGLpBmA4j/@a7@ZygvyXGdHrvv6xAl1J4cuq7m1Aw) this yields
$$T=\left(\pm\frac{ry}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}},
\frac y2 \left(1 \mp \frac{2ry}{x\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain this part: " being on the line  is =+(1−)". I understand it is some scalar multiplication of the coordinates, just not sure how you got it. 

Do you think this is the simplest form of the solution? If so I am surprised it is this complicated.

Comment: For line equation see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732147) point 3. $\\$ Yes I think it's rather simple. Anyway, as it's correct, no other can exist, so it's _the_ answer. Although the solution is not too lengthy too) Thanks.

Comment: I think there is a mistake, the second coordinate of T does not match what I have obtained empirically from my diagram.

Comment: That's fine, everyone makes mistakes. Can you please provide values for $x,y,r$ for which the coordinates of $T$ do not mathch the above? Thanks.

Comment: Actually it was my mistake, I used x: 16.7, y: 9.6, r: 2.3, and got T = (1.2, 5.5). This does not match what I had on my graph. The mistake I made was doing (y/2)(1+...), which gave 5.5. Using (y/2)(1-...) gave me the expected answer of 4.1. 
I am not sure why the solution has a plus/minus, if it impossible to obtain one of these cases empirically. For the first coordinate of T, the plus/minus makes sense since there are two tangents symmetric along the rhombus height. But for the second coordinate it does not make sense. Maybe the system was not constrained enough.

Comment: Please see [here](https://tio.run/##RcjRCoIwGIbhc69ih2qb27/AyLEuIYIOxUCmoJAJ7ieUsWtfLoJOPp7vnVoc@qnF0bQhmEq7lUsqvOp2Crpx6VWCUGnMzSEFhlneqWTeg42wotL3@fnua5ca1mVFisBmyLQW9Md/Wh7SU4fU@kYlt2V8YX2tEQgviBVx3UrYhUB54iAo2eI5l18v0fK42zdNCB8). Is the second coordinate pair $(1.1462592440991075, 4.141072530338238)$ the right one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110586/discussion-between-zr0gravity7-and-alexey-burdin).