# Trapezium, transversals...and a median?

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

$PQRS$ is a trapezium with bases $PQ$ and $RS$. $T$ is the point where diagonals $PR$ and $QS$ intercept. $U$ is a point located in side $SP$. $V$ is the point where $QS$ and $RU$ intercept. $W$ is the point where $PV$ and $TU$ intercept. $X$ is the point where $SW$ and $PQ$ intercept.

Is $X$ the middle of $QP$?

[[image: Is <span class=]$X$ middle of $QP$?" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtTov.png)

Comment: Likely [Ceva's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) or [Menelaus's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) theorems would help. [Vectors approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732147) is certainly the way to go.

Comment: Yes, $X$ is the middle of $PQ$ for arbitrary $U$, WA vectors proof [here](https://tio.run/##Lc47bsMwDAbgXafIGLHs4FUC71CgY5DBTWQ7QNPqZVm24bM7ZN1JIvn9lJ5tHtyzzY9bu@/J0Nri12YjX25436wKhipE6@VIVnmezODfzs37rLkfOLJAkHrRDM5wyifQajSUxYfUGHIHcAIiTzqIUncaRgkUCfhiqByLiwaO2cyyB/9H@386Ca28cjjowNRW/sMEtZHGJG@oj/j4yRf1@ftd3GX1kSgk5J1EcURfiPKINRH5suE644IOOyzY44DTdlXXfX8B) (see `h->1/2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The Euclidean Geometry way:

Menelaus:
${TR\over PR}\cdot{PU\over SU}\cdot{SV\over TV} = 1$

Ceva:
${TY\over PY}\cdot{PU\over SU}\cdot{SV\over TV} = 1$

Therefore ${TR\over PR}={TY\over PY}$

Draw $PZ$ parallel to $QS$ intersecting $SX$ at $Z$.

Now ${TR\over PR}={TS\over QS}$, ${TY\over PY}={TS\over PZ}$

Therefore $QS=PZ$ and $PSQZ$ is a parallelogram. Therefore $QX=XP$.

Comment: Nice a cute answer.